# jQuery scrollTop(0) causing weird scroll behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a button, a modal div fades in:

```
$('.display-all-comments').fadeIn(300);
$('.display-all-comments').scrollTop(0);
```

Without `scrollTop(0)` the scroll behaviour is normal. Here are some pics:

**Normal:**

[image]

**With scrollTop:**

[image]

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Yosemite Mac OSX. In Safari, it seems to stop scrolling altogether/all round glitchy.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. I see two windows that both seem to scroll up and down.

Comment: The scroll bar turns tiny for content it shouldn't do (both have the same number of comments). Normal shows a larger scroll bar indicating not much content to scroll, yet using scrollTop it shows a small scroll bar indicating there's lots of content to scroll, despite there not being much.

Comment: OK, I did see the scroll bar sizes, but wasn't sure if that was the whole problem you were talking about.

Comment: Can you replicate issue on jsFiddle e.g? What if you set `scrollTop(0)` in `fadeIn()` complete callback? Anyway, i'm really not sure what can cause it. BW, you talk about button click but i don't really see it in your animations and neither see anything fadeIn

Comment: @A.Wolff that seems to solve it, however, it needs to scroll to the top before it fades in. Putting it before the `fadeIn` just makes it not work altogether.

Comment: @frosty So maybe `$('.display-all-comments').scrollTop(0).fadeIn(300);` But really not clear what you are doing/expecting...

Comment: That doesn't work either. Basically a button is clicked, that white div fades in to show them all of the comments, but before it does, it needs to scroll back to the top of the div. That's because each post (I have many on the page, news-feed type thing), it empties the comments in the div to append new comments depending on which "Display all comments" they click on (different posts). So it re-uses that same div. Their scroll position might be random from the previous one they clicked, needing to scroll back to the top before the new comments are shown.

Comment: @frosty Provide concrete sample replicating your issue

Comment: Okay, I'll try and create a fiddle for you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xj6wxLek/ - Weirdly, it seems to work fine for this. I guess it has something to do with the way I append comments...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scrollTop(0)` on `fadeIn`, I instead did it on `fadeOut` (when they clicked the close button).

```
$('.display-all-comments').fadeOut(300);
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.display-all-comments').scrollTop(0);
},300)
```

This fixed the issue and achieved the same thing I wanted.

Comment: Or you could provide a callback in `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`

Comment: @dev-null true, thanks for the info. Still have a lot to learn